# Calling user controls embedded in Main window from a Control in User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a User Control (Control.xaml) in a PRoject named UserControl. I have embedded this User Control inside a Main Window in different project (Main) using

```
<commonUser:UserControl x:Name="myControl" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Now I have created a Button in User Control (Control.xaml) dynamically from code and want to access the controls of User Control. But I am not able to access the User Controls as it has become a part of Main Window. 
I can do it with the help of delegate where Button in user Control calls a method of main window and main window sends the required functionality.

I dont want to use the delegation. Is there any way to directly call the User controls from dynamically created controls.

ForExample: There is a label (label1) in Control.xaml. Now I have created a Button dynamically in Control.xaml.cs and wrting the follwoing code

```
private void button_Click(object sender , EventArgs e) {
label1.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

But label1 is not getting updated. But when Main window tells the Label to update the text it does successfully via delegation.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you may perhaps use Commands if you are interested in Click behavior.

Comment: Did not get what you mean by commands in WPF.

Comment: Every Button has a Command property which can be bound to an instance of implementation of ICommand. by doing this Execute method from the implementation will be invoked upon click of the button

Answer (score 0):

Got my work done using a Dispatcher.Invoke

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((() => {

label1.Text = "Welcome";
}));
```